# Ajax: onload serialize() form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to submit form data with ajax "onload".

Does the following jquery-ajax submit its data on load? If not how to do it?

```
<form method="GET" name="myform2" id="myform2">
<input type="hidden" name="car" value="bmw">
<input type="hidden" name="moto" value="honda">
<button id="submit2" type="submit" value="submit2" name="submit2">
```

Js

```
            $(document).ready(function(){      
            function sssssss2(page){
            var form2 = document.myform2;
            var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize() + '&page=' + page;
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "query.php",
                    data: dataString1,
                    success: function(ccc)
                    {
                     $("#search_results").html(ccc);
                    }
                });
            }
            sssssss2(1) ;
            $('#search_results .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                sssssss2(page);                 
            });  
            });
```

Comment: Your code will submit the dataString when the document is Ready, not completely loaded. note that ".live" is deprecated, use ".on" instead, only you can check if the data reaches the server

Comment: yep, the above ajax code will submit the data onload.Avoid using `.live()` its been deprecated  in versions above 1.7 and removed in version 1.9, application becomes unstable when deprecated functions are called,instead use `.on()` function for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both document ready and window load both occur roughly at the same time.

But you can also write like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
      // your code here
});
```

This function will execute when window is loaded fully.
and yes use .on inspite of .live().